# How to evaluate $-\frac{1}{2}[xe^{-x^2}]|_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$?

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral

I'm trying to solve the following integral: $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^2e^{-x^2} dx$. I used integration by parts to get:
$$-\frac{1}{2}[xe^{-x^2}]|_{-\infty}^{+\infty}+\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2} dx$$

I solved the gaussian integral easily, but I don't know how to evaluate the first term. After looking around a bit, I learned that it has to be 0. How?
Thank you.

Comment: Is the exponent supposed to be negative?

Comment: Are you sure that you have copied the problem correctly? I don't think that the integral you have given has an antiderivative in terms of elementary functions...

Comment: yes! i forgot the negative sign! Regarding the problem, it is correct and I further found out that it has to evaluate to $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$

Comment: Have you learnt about the expectation and variance of standard normal distribution?

Comment: Any idea of what $\infty e^{-\infty^2}$ could evaluate to ?